# CyanogenMod bug report tracking

Tags: cyanogenmod

When I submit a bug report from my phone running CyanogenMod, can I track it on the web? If so, how and where? 
I tried jira.cyanogenmod.org but was unable to find my report.

Comment: Have you tried [searching on it](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/issues/)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes i have tried searching. Is it possible they filter out reports with small descriptions?

Comment: I'm not sure about that (I never use it though). On the other hand, on the left sidebar, there's a filter to get issues "Reported by me". If that doesn't help, I don't know what else...

Comment: actually, I don't have an account there. I just submitted a bug report from my phone and was trying to find it on jira.

Comment: You might get better answers on that topic in the CyanogenMod forum, as there they should know.